# HTC Desire resolution of the screen

Tags: resolution, android

I took a look at the phone specifications and is says something like this

"HTC Desire. It comes with a 3.7" LCD screen (480 x 800 pixels of resolution)"

ok the screen is 480x800 pixels but how many dips it has ? and how do I calculate that.

Also it is confusing for me the fact that Desire HD has the same resolution 480x800 pixcels, and they both use hdpi images. I have application and when I install myApp they both use the images from hdpi folder

can someone tall me what is the resolution in dips in desire and desireHD ?

Comment: Try to read and understand this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: dips ALLWAYS are the same to all resolution, thats is the cause you must to use it, with dips your apps allways look the same in all devices (better i put "allways" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information about display, such as size, density, and font scaling using [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html).

Documentation gives a usage example.